# Visual components from external libraries not visible in design view of visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017, dxf

I'm doing maintenance on a GUI, made in C#, using Visual Studio (xaml technology).

There are several visual components I don't see in the design view, like the Telerik and DXF visual components. I have no idea if this is due to a general problems ("Visual Studio Design view has problems external visual components") or if this is a specific problem for the visual components' libraries ("Telerik is not viewable in Visual Studio's Design view" or "In order to see DXF visual components in Visual Studio's Design view, you need to configure ...").

An example of a Telerik visual component in the XAML:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=client:View}}">
    <telerik:RadBusyIndicator Name="BusyIndicator"
    ....
```

An example of a DXF visual component in the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <netDxf:DxfViewer Name="dxfViewer"
...
```

How can I make a start on this?

### Edit

Meanwhile I've understood that `DXF` is CAD technology. I'm working with Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, version 15.9.44. The `DXF` viewer in XAML design is at the moment the most important.

Comment: are you expecting same display as runtime(e.g.the dxf preview image) at design time? or, just want the control's rectangle be shown at design time?

Comment: @LeiYang: I am seeing everything fine at runtime, but I don't see anything at design time. I would like to see at design time what it looks like.

Comment: i want it at design time too. but the reality is not showing, even many times wpf built in controls not show at design time.

Comment: @LeiYang: I'm taking over a WPF project from a previous collegue. The whole screen is a DXF screen, which I would like to update. Without DXF viewer, built in Visual Studio, this is enormous difficult, hence my question and the corresponding bounty.

Comment: i think the downvote and close is due to we can do little about it. VS is a commercial product.

Comment: @LeiYang: who should I contact for such kind of questions then?

Comment: first the control vendor, sencond microsoft, or their forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add the Telerik controls manually by choosing the toolbox items. They have [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/integration/installation-adding-to-vs-toolbox) on the process.

I don't know of an extension that exists already for DXP files on the Marketplace, but you can write your own Visual Studio extension to read in the file and tell Visual Studio how to format it.

This [repository](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Editor_With_Toolbox) does such thing, but it uses a much simpler example to help guide you along the process.